# Share network connection via management port?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a Gen6 HP Proliant ml110.
Is it possible to share an internet connection through the iLO's management NIC port?

That is, would it be possible for a computer connected to the management port to share an upstream Internet connection?

And how would I do this on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Comment: "management port" can mean lots of things. What hardware are you talking about? Management port on what piece of equipment?

Comment: It is a port labelled MGMT which i can fit an Ethernet cable into it, however it doesn't show up if i do ifconfig.

Comment: That doesn't tell us a whole lot. What kind of server is it on? Lots of equipment has RJ45 ports like that which are not actually Ethernet interfaces, and are instead meant for special serial console cables.
You'll get more help if you can post more information in your question.

Comment: In the manual it is labelled as a Management Nic port, and i can plug an Ethernet cable into it. I'm not really sure what it is, which is why i have asked if its possible to use it as an ethernet connection. I am not really sure what extra information i should incllude

Comment: Relevant information includes things like the manufacturer name, the model of the device, and other information. We still don't know what kind of device you're talking about. It could be a server or a very silly toaster at this point, but you haven't provided any information as to which.

Comment: Oh, my server is a HP proliant ml110 g6 and It is running ubuntu server. (also i would like to see a toaster with an rj45 port :) )

Comment: It would be a *very* silly toaster. ;) I've edited your question to better reflect what you're trying to accomplish, and to clarify the hardware you're using. I'm going to start looking, but I'm not sure that version of the HPiLO (what that management device is called) had the kind of functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: No, it doesn't work that way.

On Gen6, HP was shipping iLO v2.

The [HPiLO2 User Guide is available from HP here](https://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00553302.pdf) as a PDF.

While the iLO is able to inspect and monitor the server, it is not possible for the OS on the server to use the iLO's NIC as it's own - they are functionally separate devices. The manual does not describe a way for you to use the iLO as an additional network interface accessible to the OS, which is what would be necessary for you to share an Internet connection in the way that you describe.

Indeed, at the bottom of p62, into p63 is this sentence:

> You can only use the iLO 2 Shared Network Port and the iLO 2 Dedicated Management NIC port for iLO 2 server management.

This confirms that, no, you cannot configure the Management NIC the way that you describe.